# Why does using rank() windowing function break the parser?

Tags: sql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

The windowing functions online docs for spark sql include the following example:

https://databricks.com/blog/2015/07/15/introducing-window-functions-in-spark-sql.html

```
SELECT
  product,
  category,
  revenue
FROM (
  SELECT
    product,
    category,
    revenue,
    dense_rank() OVER (PARTITION BY category ORDER BY revenue DESC) as rank
  FROM productRevenue) tmp
WHERE
  rank <= 2
```

I have created what would seem to be a similar structure sql. But it does not work

```
select id,r from (
          select id, name, 
          rank() over (partition by name order by name) as r
          from tt) v 
          where v.r >= 7 and v.r <= 12
```

Here is the error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException: [3.25] 
      failure: ``)'' expected but `(' found

            rank() over (partition by fp order by fp) as myrank
                        ^
```

Anyone can see where they differ structurally?  I am on spark 1.6.0-SNAPSHOT from 11/18/15.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I checked the source code and it appears the rank() requires **hive** support. I am rebuilding spark with

```
 -Phive -Phive-thriftserver
```

I did confirm: when using a `HiveContext` the query works.

Comment: What does it mean rebuilding? Where should I do this?

Comment: @AswinJoseRoy  If you were building Spark yourself on Maven those options need to be included. If you were downloading pre-built Spark you need to get a version that includes Hive support.