# Spark dataframe drop duplicates

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, duplicates

Is it possible possible to tell spark drop duplicates to drop the second occurrence instead of first one?

```
scala> df.show()
+-----------+
|         _1|
+-----------+
|1 2 3 4 5 6|
|9 4 5 8 7 7|
|1 2 3 4 5 6|
+-----------+


scala> val newDf = df.dropDuplicates()
newDf: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [_1: string]

scala> newDf.show()
+-----------+                                                                   
|         _1|
+-----------+
|9 4 5 8 7 7|
|1 2 3 4 5 6|
+-----------+
```

Comment: You can use window functions http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35498162/spark-remove-duplicate-rows-from-dataframe Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Ranking/indexing on rows, having same values and then drop entries for all records having index/rank > 1.